# Should Flannel run on a Kubernetes master?

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I've successfully deployed a Kubernetes 1.3.5 cluster on 1 master + 6 nodes (all running CentOS) including the DNS and Kubernetes Dashboard addons. Everything seemed to be working OK at first. However, when I tried to run

```
kubectl proxy --address=<master-external-ip> --port=9090 --disable-filter
```

and access `http://<master-external-ip>:9090/ui` I got the following output

```
Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.38.2:9090: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'http://172.16.38.2:9090/'
```

However, if I start `flanneld` on the master everything works and I can actually reach the Dashboard. Now, I've used `kube-up.sh` to install the cluster and it didn't install any configs or `systemd` service for Flannel, which leaves me confused—should Flannel also run on the master?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it should, otherwise packets going through the API server proxy can not be routed to their final destination: the dashboard pod running on some other machine.

Comment: Should flannel run on it's own on the master node or is there any required configuration I should add on the kube-apiserver | controller-manager | scheduler services? Is it enough to just have a flannel interface up and running (and getting an IP from etcd obviously) ?

Comment: No need to configure anything on the Kubernetes side. Flannel is just taking care of routing the packets, Kubernetes is not aware of which network fabric is being used at the infrastructure level.

Comment: I assume that's just for the master/controller use case right? Because on the worker I need to setup flannel AND configure CNI & the kubelet to use it. Correct?

Comment: Correct but there's a distinction between the network fabric and CNI. CNI is invoked by the kubelet only, and is used to perform the network plumbing on the containers. The container network is the foundation for routing the packets between these containers. Both can be set up independently.

Comment: Wish I could +1 more than once. Thanks for the very insightful comments. One last thing: to use flannel you also need to configure the kublet to use CNI with the flannel plugin and k8s (kubelet) will create a new network bridge that will replace docker0 as far as I understand. That cni configuration (for the flanneld use case only) would look something like this:

    {
        "name": "cbr0",
        "type": "flannel",
        "delegate": {
            "isDefaultGateway": true
        }
    }

Comment: No docker0 will not be replaced by the flannel.1 network, but the Docker network will be configured to use Flannel for outgoing traffic (see https://github.com/jonashackt/kubernetes-the-ansible-way#flannel-with-docker for more details).